# How do I reset a counter variable in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-pipelines

How do I reset a counter variable in Azure Pipelines?  Is it possible?

When I first moved my build to Azure, the build version was `2.0.202.0` (***major.minor.build.0***) So I set up my variables like this (with a '203' seed so as not to break continuity):

```
variables:
  major: 2
  minor: 0
  semantic: $(major).$(minor)
  buildNum: $[counter(variables['semantic'], 203)]
```

This worked great and so far I'm up to build `2.0.256.0`.

When I changed the minor version from 0 to 1 (and removed the '203' seed), I thought it would make the counter reset and my "buildNum" value would be 0.  But that's not what happened.

Here are the values I tried in order and what I got for each build

```
Value of 'buildNum' variable'                   Result     Comment
==========================                      =======    ======================
patch: $[counter(variables['semantic'])]        257        just kept incrementing
patch: $[counter(variables['$(semantic)'])]     6222       ???  Where did this come from?
patch: $[counter(variables[$(semantic)], 0)]    (none)     Error: did not even build
patch: $[counter(variables['2.1'], 0)]          6223       Just incremented the 6222
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the variable expression `$()` which is nested in expression `$[]` cannot be fully evaluated when it is used in **Variables** section.

The `variables['semantic']` inside `$[counter(variables['semantic'], 203)]` will be evaluated to `$(major).$(minor)` instead of `2.0`. You can tested it by below expression.

```
variables:
  major: 2
  minor: 0
  semantic: $(major).$(minor)
  flag1: $[eq(variables['semantic'], '$(major).$(minor)')]
  flag2: $[eq(variables['semantic'], '2.0')]

steps:
- checkout: none
- powershell: |
    echo "flag1---$(flag1)"  #will be true
    echo "flag2--$(flag2)"  #will be false
```

In above example flag1 will be true and flag2 will be false. See below:

[image]

The way to fix it is to use expression `${{}}` for the variable `semantic`, which will be evaluated at [compile time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax).

Change your `semantic` variable as below:

```
variables:
  major: 2
  major: 1
  semantic: ${{variables.major}}.${{variables.minor}}
  buildNum: $[counter(variables['semantic'], 203)]
```

Or just use the actual value `2.0` of `$(major).$(minor)` in the `buildNum` expression. See below:

```
variables:
  major: 2
  major: 1
  semantic: $(major).$(minor)
  buildNum: $[counter(2.1, 203)]
```

Comment: The approach with the literal 2.1 worked like a champ, thanks.  I was unable to make the approach with the double brackets work -- it just gave me build number 6224 (the next number in the weird ones I got starting in 6222, no idea where that came from).